# Visual Basic 2010 Regex.Matches , ¿cómo hacer para que encuentre un texto que contiene el los caracteres "\b"?

Tags: regex

Tengo un texto así: a4 b4 \bar "|." \tuplet3/2{c'8  d'8  a8} \bar "|." c,4 \bar "|."  aa8 b16 c16

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que  Regex.Matches encuentre las ocurrencia de **\bar**

¿Cómo se puede hacer ésto? ¿Alguien me echa una mano por favor?

Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo encontré. El truco es usar doble barra en vez de barra simple en la búsqueda

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], aunque mencionas la solución la misma es muy corta y pobre de contenido y explicación lo que podría traerte negativos